# Problem in UITabbarcontroller with UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to load the second view of the tabbar in my application.So i did the code like this

```
tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

In my second view has 4 UISegmentedItem.How do i load the 4 segmented view at the first time.Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a BOOL variable in AppDelgate class and where you switch the tab view set that BOOl to yes
and on viewWillAppear of the view on which segment controller present check the BOOL value and according to that
setSelectedIndex=3 for segment controller.